# Executable jar - loading truststore from projects resources

Tags: java, classloader, executable-jar, runnable, truststore

I am aware that are many similar problems, I think I have read and checked all possibilities and have no idea what I'm doing wrong...

I am loading to System properties two certificates files from project's resources package, and than connecting with them to JMS server. When running application in Eclipse mode everything works fine, problem occurres when trying to read resource from runnable JAR file, it causes an error:

```
FileNotFoundException: file:\path_to_my_jar!\resources\serverids.jks
```

The files are places inside jar (in main folder). This folder is placed in `src/resources`, but I have tried creating resources folder outside src and linking it to build path with the same result.

This is how I'm reading the file and setting properties for connectionManager:

```
    ClassLoader currentClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    String keyStore =  currentClassLoader.getResource("resources/serverids.jks").getPath();
    String trustStore =  currentClassLoader.getResource("resources/server.truststore").getPath();

    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", keyStore);
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "pass");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", trustStore);
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "pass");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get this resource as a `InputStream` and then read it to `String` to the property value you'd like to set. Also, in your case you should extract the resource this way:

`CurrentClass.class.getResourceAsStream("blah.jks")`

Please, don't forget to close the stream after processing.

Comment: Unfortunatelly it also causes null pointer exception ;/

I'm wondering if it could be problem with this JMS certificates, that they cannot be loaded as stream? But absolute path to file like C:/temp/etc... works fine (but it is terrible solution....)

Comment: What you should do is in debug mode try out different paths for the resource (during the inspection mode) - this will make it much faster for you to find how to get to the desired resource.